# How to first remove every second element on a list, then every third on whats remaining?

Tags: python, list

Say:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I know that `list[::2]` would remove every second element, so `list = [1,3,5,7,9]`
What if say I then needed to remove every third element? So list would become `[1,3,7,9]` (5 would be removed since it is the third element. How would I then proceed to do that?
Currently, using `b = list[::3]` returns `[1, 7]`

Comment: `list[::2]` would *pick* every second element. `del list[::2]` would remove those elements from the original list..

Comment: You asked a question, and answered it! Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: `list[::3]` does return `[1, 7]` after `list = list[::2]`

Comment: Thanks to Martjin. That was the problem, I was returning every third element instead of deleting it

Answer (score 16):

To *delete* elements from a given list, use `del`:

```
del lst[::2]  # delete every second element (counting from the first)
del lst[::3]  # delete every third
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> del lst[::2]
>>> lst
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> del lst[::3]
>>> lst
[4, 6, 10]
```

If you wanted to delete the second element counting from the second, you'd need to give the slice a starting index other than the default:

```
del lst[1::2]  # delete every second element, starting from the second
del lst[2::3]  # delete every third element, starting from the third
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> del lst[1::2]
>>> lst
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> del lst[2::3]
>>> lst
[1, 3, 7, 9]
```

Comment: note that `del[lst::2]` does not remove every second element, it removes every second element STARTING WITH THE FIRST element. Perhaps `del lst[1::2]` then `del lst[2::3]`

Comment: What if the order was reversed or modifiable, instead of deleting every second, you would begin by deleting every third, and then deleting every second

Comment: @Anonmly: Then you'd be deleting different elements; the order of selecting elements is important here.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial statement saves every other value it does not delete it. You should also not make your variable "list".

given the original values you show above

```
del mylist[::2]
```

will return the even values of the list while

```
del mylist[1::2]
```

will return the odd values as you request. Following that the standard

```
del mylist[::3]
```

will remove the third value of the list as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

For the incredibly long one-liner:

```
>>> [el for i,el in enumerate([el for i,el in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) if (i+1)%2]) if (i+1)%3]
[1,3,7,9]
```

Pseudocode for the above:

```
for (index, value) in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
    if index+1 is divisible by 2: toss it
    else: add it to new_list

for (index, value) in new_list:
    if index+1 is divisible by 3: toss it
    else: add it to final_list

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_nums(int_list):
    #list starts with 0 index
    position = 3 - 1 
    idx = 0
    len_list = (len(int_list))
    
    while len_list>0:
        idx = (position+idx)%len_list
        print(int_list.pop(idx))
        len_list -= 1
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    remove_nums(nums)
```